# Dropped Wireless Headphone in Handbrake

Tags: nissan, handbrake, versa

I drive a manual transmission 2013 nissan versa base model. I dropped a wireless headphone through the gap between my center console and the hand brake. Does anyone know where I can find instructions on how to remove the center console so I can get to my headphone?

Comment: You may be able to get it from underneath the car without removing anything. If it isn't on top of the gearbox housing it will have fallen off onto the road somewhere. You probably can't *see* the top of the gearbox, but you can reach it with your hand and feel for the headphones.

Answer (score 1):

I would inspect the console in detail to work out where the fixings are.

Some have screws that are only visible when the ashtray is removed for example, others rely on hidden clips where one has to prise the covers off to get to screws etc

The only place where there will be detailed instructions will be in the workshop manual. However the exploded parts diagram may also be useful - if the dealer will show you that. I did that often but I had a good relationship with dealers...